# Where do I put my helpers and how do I test them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, helper

This is my first on StackOverflow and I'm a new rails developer.

I'm using RoR to create an inventory application for Magic: The Gathering cards.  I've found a Json API that I'd like to use to pull data on all of the cards, sets, etc into a local database.

My initial inclination is to create a helper class to manage all of this (which can also be called in seeds.rb during db:setup), but I have no idea where I should put this class in my project's directory structure.  It's not really a model/controller/view, so I feel it should be kept separate from those parts of the app.

Further more, I'm having trouble testing any class I do make.  I initially created a directory app/classes and put the class there.  Then in my spec directory, I created spec/classes and created the spec file.  Accessing my helper class from the spec did not work in the same way that accessing my models in their spec classes did.

I'm at a loss as to how to do this and quite a bit of googling and searching on here has just left me more confused.  I'd love any help that can be offered.  How would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention specifically what issues you're encountering, but for starters app/classes isn't in rails's autoload path - rails' `require` magic doesn't know to look in there to find these classes (as an aside, 'classes' sounds like a slightly meaningless name - models & controllers are classes too).

You can add to the paths rails searches (see `config.autoload_paths` in config/application.rb) but I would put this in lib (and the corresponding specs in spec/lib).

It would also work just fine with these classes in app/models, whether or not it does there is down to choice. There's nothing that says that files in there have to be active record subclasses - the decision of whether or not this functionality belongs in there  boils down to whether it works/feels like a model to you.

Comment: Thanks.  What I ended up doing is putting it under lib/helpers and I managed to get some tests around it working.  I created the helper as a module, however it was erroring in tests because I defined the module as "Module" instead of "module", which was causing some errors.

I don't think putting it in the Models directory was really clean.  This is more of a wrapper for an API and an activerecord class.